# How to handle different distribution of feature column in below case?

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, feature-extraction, feature-engineering

I am working with a tabular dataset of around 20k entries for training(mixed with categorical and numeric features) and around 2k entries to predict.

After cleaning, I wanted to keep just about 2% of data for holdout and rest I will use for cross validation.

```
X_train, X_val, y_train, y_val = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.02, random_state=42)
model = CatBoostClassifier(n_estimators=1000, scale_pos_weight=0.244, eval_metric='BalancedAccuracy')

cv = RepeatedStratifiedKFold(n_splits=10, n_repeats=3, random_state=1)
n_scores = cross_val_score(model, X_train, y_train, scoring='balanced_accuracy', cv=cv, n_jobs=-1, error_score='raise')

print('MAE: %.3f (%.3f)' % (np.mean(n_scores), np.std(n_scores)))
```

Here I am getting `0.735` as balanced accuracy.

then I fit the model with whole data.

```
model = CatBoostClassifier(n_estimators=1000, scale_pos_weight=0.244, eval_metric='BalancedAccuracy')
model.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

And tested the holdout data we kept separately.

```
y_val_pred = model.predict(X_val)
balanced_accuracy_score(y_val, y_val_pred)
```

we got `0.7428` as balanced accuracy.

Now, this dataset about offers to different companies (and different info about the offer and company itself) and we have to predict whether the bids will be accepted or rejected.

So, I wanted to add some feature that is related to overall stat of companies.

```
total_count = dict(training_set.groupby(['CUSTOMER']).size())
positive_count = training_set.groupby("CUSTOMER").OFFER_STATUS.agg(lambda x: sum(x))

success_rate = dict()
for cust in total_count:
  success_rate[cust] = positive_count[cust] / total_count[cust]

total_data_count = dict(all_merged_data.groupby(['CUSTOMER']).size())

training_set["NUM_OFFER"] = training_set.CUSTOMER.apply(lambda x: total_count.get(x, np.nan))
training_set["SUCCESS_RATE"] = training_set.CUSTOMER.apply(lambda x: success_rate.get(x, np.nan))
training_set["NUM_OFFER_FULL"] = training_set.CUSTOMER.apply(lambda x: total_data_count.get(x, np.nan))
training_set['OFFER_RATE_PER_YEAR'] = training_set.apply(lambda x: x.NUM_OFFER_FULL / x.AGE, axis=1)
```

And instantly I see a huge improvement in the accuracy both in cross-validation and holdout test.

`MAE: 0.829 (0.010)` and `0.831` respectively.

But, when I submit it, it fails miserably and performs even worse than the previous model on test. (I don't know the exact number, but it's below the earlier one in internal rank, should be around 65%)

The reason I found out is the frequencies of column ids are of different distribution in training and test. That is, one column id that is most frequent in training (about 200 times in training) occurs only once in test, and vice verca.

So, for the ids that appears only once in training, builds feature only on those 1 instance, and then predict badly in those 50 instance in test.

My question is, how to design my pipeline to tackle the issue and improve my performance on test?

Comment: Is training_set the full data set or the one after you've applied the train_test split?

Comment: @SimonHawe training_set is the full dataset. same as [X y].